Copiar setting.php de drupa usando initContainers de kubernetes
Estoy tratando de desplegar docker en kubernetes a través de archivos de configuración yaml.
Me funciona todo correctamente, pero cuando accedo a drupal a través del navegador usando loclahost, comienzo el proceso de instalación pero me aparece los errores:

"The default settings file does not exist.
The Drupal installer requires that the ./sites/default/default.settings.php file must not be deleted or modified from the original download."
"The Settings file does not exist.
The Drupal installer requires that you create a ./sites/default/settings.php as part of the installation process. Copy the ./sites/default/default.settings.php file to ./sites/default/settings.php. More details about installing Drupal are available in INSTALL.txt."

Creo que tiene que ver por el uso de initContainers en mi archivo yaml, pero necesito usarlos. Mi archivo de configuración es el siguiente:
# PersistentVolumeClaim para Drupal
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: drupal-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
# Service para Drupal
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: drupal
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    app: drupal
---
# Deployment de Drupal
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: drupal
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: drupal
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: drupal
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: init-drupal
          image: drupal:latest
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - |
              # Verificar si el archivo settings.php ya existe, de lo contrario crearlo y asignar permisos
              if [ ! -f /var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php ]; then
                cp /var/www/html/sites/default/default.settings.php /var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php
              fi
              chmod 664 /var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php
              chmod 775 /var/www/html/sites/default
              
              # Crear el directorio de traducciones con permisos de escritura
              mkdir -p /var/www/html/sites/default/files/translations
              chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/sites/default/files
              
              # Verificar que el archivo y el directorio existen
              ls -la /var/www/html/sites/default/
              ls -la /var/www/html/sites/default/files/translations
          volumeMounts:
            - name: drupal-storage
              mountPath: /var/www/html/sites/default
      containers:
        - image: drupal:latest
          name: drupal
          env:
            - name: DRUPAL_DB_HOST
              value: mysql
            - name: DRUPAL_DB_NAME
              value: drupal
            - name: DRUPAL_DB_USER
              value: drupal
            - name: DRUPAL_DB_PASSWORD
              value: drupalpassword
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/html/sites/default
              name: drupal-storage
      volumes:
        - name: drupal-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: drupal-pvc

Ayuda por favor.
